# "IF" branching vs. arithmetic tradeoff in shaders?

Tags: opengl, unity-game-engine, mobile, shader, cg

Supposing I need this function in a shader:

```
if (y < 1) return x/y;
else
{
    if (x < 0.5) return x;
    else if (x < y -0.5) return 0.5;
    else return x - y + 1;
}
```

This can be achieved without `if` branches, like:

```
return 
(x/y) +
max(0,y-1)/(y-1) *
(
    2 * (max(y - 0.5, x)-(y - 1)) * min(0.5, x)
    -(x/y)
);
```

**Is this the second function really worth the trade?**
Regarding performance. That seems a lot computation.
But they say `if` branching is no-go for fixed pipeline GPUs.

I would not ask if the second function would not involve computations that many.

Comment: @nicol-bolas Is it a tradeoff in this specific case?

Comment: Well, your "specific case" lacks specifics. And even if you did provide those specifics, it's unlikely that anyone could answer that without compiling it and seeing what the performance is like.

Comment: Well I did it actually, tried with 3 different case (the middle was a hybrid), but did not experienced any (!!!) difference in the fill rate. Other may had similar experiences in the past, and could warn me something like: Hey dude, it is not that big deal! Your `if` statements would be just fine.

Comment: Inside a CG Shader on an iPad 3.